# Printing from database

Tags: mysql

Im trying to make a system that will print label's. but dont know how to make it as i want. It is working when i only have one row in the DB, but when i get more rows, that is when i hit some problems with the layout.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Din Matmerking</title>

    <!-- style -->
    <link href="config/stil/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="config/stil/oppskrift.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="config/stil/merk.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <!-- <link href="/config/stil/base_style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> -->

    <!-- W3 -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">


    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
</head>

<body>
    <div id="main" class="container">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <div class="logo"><img src="/img/Logo2.png" class="img-responsive"></div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Velkommen</a>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="/login/welcome.php">Hjem</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/bin/appdata/oppskrift-bok.asp">Oppskrifter</a></li>
                        <li><a href="../appdata/merkelapper.php">Matmerking</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><a href="/index.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span> Logg ut</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="well">
                    <div id="printableArea">
                        <form id="merk">
                            <table>
                                <thead>
                                    <!-- <tr>
                                    <th id="text">Matmerking</th>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th><br></th>
                                </tr> -->
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <?php
                                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                                        {
                                            echo '
                                            <tr>
                                            <td id="text"><b>Produkt:&ensp;</b></td>
                                            <td><b>'.$row["name"].'</b></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                            <td id="text"><b>Laget:&ensp;</b></td>
                                            <td><b>'.$row["produsert"].'</b></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                            <td id="text"><b>Holdbarhet:&ensp;</b></td>
                                            <td><b>'.$row["holdbarhet"].'</b></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                            <td id="text"><b>Pris pr kg:&ensp;</b></td>
                                            <td><b>'.$row["pris_kg"].'&ensp;,-</b></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                            <td id="text"><b>Laget av:&ensp;</b></td>
                                            <td><b>'.$row["signatur"].'</b></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            ';
                                        }
                                ?>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="printDiv('printableArea')" value="Print" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-footer">
                <br>
                <label><p>&copy; DIN-MATMERKING.NO 2017</p></label>
                <br>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function printDiv(divName) {
            var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
            var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;
            document.body.innerHTML = printContents;
            window.print();
            document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
 }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I want the user to be able to chose form a name that is displyed in a table whit data from MySqlDB.

this is how I want it to be displayed:

[image]

Here you see how it looks when I have more rows in the DB:

[image]

Any adwise? Maybe ita possible to have a DB table displayd in html and have it so the name can be a link and open a modual where the info i want printed out is displayd.

```
<?php
$connect = mysqli_connect("connection", 
"username", "password", "DB");
$query = "SELECT * FROM merkelapp";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
?>
```

[DB structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TuFFe.png)

Comment: We couldn't possibly know without first seeing your query and example of the DB structure & data

Comment: Im not sure what you mean? Im a noob to all this. But if you can explain it a bit more i might be able to get the info i miss.

Comment: Sure - We need to see the part of the code where you query the Database - That part where you `SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ...` and you can upload a screenshot of the table with the data from phpMyAdmin (I didn't Downvote BTW)

Comment: Hello, please take a look at [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and help us help you by providing a [minimal complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you have attempted thus far.

Comment: I think i have added what you are asking for.

Comment: OK, so basically you want a separate table and print button for each row, that when clicked will print the relevant part using the current `printDiv` function?

Comment: Yes. the user on the page will make labels that will be saved to the DB and then they can later, when they need the label, they can just press print and it will print out the selected label.

Comment: Its a foodlabel system. First you make a recepi, and then the recepi makes a label from the info they gave. Then when they have made the food they need to label it.

Comment: Don't assign to `document.body.innerHTML`, use media queries to show different content when printing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the basic structure of your HTML should be as follows, for each label:

```
<div id="printableArea"> <!-- HERE YOU MUST HAVE A UNIQUE ID FOR EACH LABEL -->
    <form id="merk"> <!-- HERE YOU MUST HAVE A UNIQUE ID FOR EACH LABEL AS WELL -->
        <table><!-- LABEL DETAILS --></table>

        <!-- HERE YOU NEED TO PASS THE UNIQUE ID OF THE AREA YOU WANT TO PRINT -->
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="printDiv('printableArea')" value="Print" /> 
    </form>
</div>
```

My suggestion is that you create a separate `.well` wrapper for each label, and by using the unique `id` of each row in the **merkelapp** table, you can create a unique ID attributes for your elements:

```
<?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
<div class="well">
    <div id="printableArea<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
        <form id="merk<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
            <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td id="text"><b>Produkt:&ensp;</b></td>
                    <td><b><?php echo $row["name"]; ?></b></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td id="text"><b>Laget:&ensp;</b></td>
                    <td><b><?php echo $row["produsert"]; ?></b></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td id="text"><b>Holdbarhet:&ensp;</b></td>
                    <td><b><?php echo $row["holdbarhet"]; ?></b></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td id="text"><b>Pris pr kg:&ensp;</b></td>
                    <td><b><?php echo $row["pris_kg"]; ?>&ensp;,-</b></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td id="text"><b>Laget av:&ensp;</b></td>
                    <td><b><?php echo $row["signatur"]; ?></b></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            </table>
        </form>
    </div>
    <br>
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="printDiv('printableArea<?php echo $row['id']; ?>')" value="Print" />
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Note that I appended the ID of each row after the id attributes (`printableArea<?php echo $row['id']; ?>`) so the output of the id's will be `printableArea1`, `printableArea2`, `printableArea3` and so on. I did the same for each form (`merk1`, `merk2`...).

I also changed the `printDiv('printableArea')` and added the row ID there so when you click on a button, it will pass the correct ID to that function.

As a side note, I recommend to escape the output using [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) so characters like `>` will not break the HTML structure by replacing it with the corresponding `&gt;`, so instead of just having:

```
<td><b><?php echo $row["name"]; ?></b></td>
```

You output it like this:

```
<td><b><?php echo htmlentities( $row["name"] ); ?></b></td>
```